# Combine Multiple Select Statements from different tables

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework

i have the  this MYSQL SP that does SUm against different tables but i wanted the SP to return all the results in one table one row i tried using + to combine results from the selects but it gets error

```
 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS x.GetFinanceContent;
 delimiter //
 CREATE PROCEDURE x.GetFinanceContent
    (
         IN  userId INT

    )
 BEGIN
 (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS creditTotal
    FROM x.Card1 
    WHERE user_Id = userId and card_type=1) 
    +

 (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS debitTotal
    FROM x.Card2 
    WHERE user_Id = userId and card_type=2) 


 END;//
```

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '+    (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS
>   debitTotal
>       FROM x.Card 
>       WHERE user_Id ' at line 10    0.000 sec

Comment: You are selecting from the same table, `x.Card`?

Comment: This is (basically) a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175686/inserting-sum-of-2-tables-into-a-row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    ( SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS creditTotal
      FROM x.Card1
      WHERE user_Id = userId AND card_type=1
    )  
  , ( SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS debitTotal
      FROM x.Card2
      WHERE user_Id = userId AND card_type=2
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to SUM those sums you can make query like this:

```
SELECT ((SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS creditTotal
    FROM x.Card1 
    WHERE user_Id = userId and card_type=1) + 
(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS debitTotal
    FROM x.Card2 
    WHERE user_Id = userId and card_type=2)) as total
```

Use union http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html If you want to get one result set....

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS x.GetFinanceContent;
 delimiter //
 CREATE PROCEDURE x.GetFinanceContent
    (
         IN  userId INT

    )
 BEGIN
 (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS creditTotal
    FROM x.Card1 
    WHERE user_Id = userId and card_type=1) 

 UNION

 (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS debitTotal
    FROM x.Card2 
    WHERE user_Id = userId and card_type=2) 


 END;//
```

Although I am rusty now with SQL and too lazy to check if syntax is correct, I think it should work.

Comment: sorry... seems that I misunderstood your real question :).